# How to update 400 000 records through batch wise

Tags: postgresql, out-of-memory, batch-processing

I have the following table named `business_extra`

```
business_id    address      neighbourhood
==========================================
1
2
3
..
400 000 records
```

The `address` column contains null values, so I want to update that column using another table

I have written the following query:

```
update b2g_mns_v2.txn_business_extra a 
   set mappable_address=b.mappable_address 
from b2g_mns_v2.temp_business b 
where b.import_reference_id=a.import_reference_id
```

but got the error message:

> out of shared memory

Comment: And how much shared memory do you have? And what about changing this setting? lakh is something that I don't use, please translate.

Comment: Please show us the execution plan of the statement and any indexes defined on the involved tables.

Comment: You only want to update where the address is currently null, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
update b2g_mns_v2.txn_business_extra a 
   set mappable_address=b.mappable_address 
from b2g_mns_v2.temp_business b 
where b.import_reference_id=a.import_reference_id
and a.mappable_address is null
limit 10000
```

Do this a few times (batches of 10000).
As a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, better ensure you query is OK by providing the execution plan.